# Upload image from react native to server has empty body

Tags: ios, react-native, upload, axios, fetch

i'm trying to upload image from react native to server (Django or Nodejs) and after lots of searches i didn't find anything and still the body and files parameters of my request is empty.

My react native method :

```
 const data = new FormData();
        data.append('file', {
            uri: this.state.logoimg.path,
            type: 'image/jpeg', // or photo.type
            name: 'testPhotoName'
        });
        fetch(url, {
            method: 'post',
            body: data
        }).then(res => {
            console.log(res)
        });
```

I use react-native-image-crop-picker and this.state.logoimg is that response.

Comment: You have to pass a [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) or [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) object to [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)

Comment: Please send an example